# SLR Policy to grant user permission to create Organization

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-policies

I want to have an IAM user that has the ability to create an IAM Organization and nothing more.

To achieve this, I need to create a policy that is using SLR.

I am attaching the policy to the group that my IAM belongs to.

If I use the general SLR permission policy I can create an Organization with any user.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/*"
}
```

When I specify the exact user resource that I want to have those permissions I can't do it anymore.

this is the template provided in the aws docs

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/SERVICE-NAME.amazonaws.com/SERVICE-LINKED-ROLE-NAME-PREFIX*",
   "Condition": {"StringLike": {"iam:AWSServiceName": "SERVICE-NAME.amazonaws.com"}}
},
```

this is mine

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::000056397000:user/root_name:role/aws-service-role/organizations.amazonaws.com/*"
}
```

the error I get is:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedForDependencyException) when calling the CreateOrganization operation: The

request failed because your credentials do not have permission to create the service-linked role required 

by AWS Organizations.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around.
Not ideal, maybe someone has a better idea.

Group with 2 policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/organizations.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "organizations.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "organizations:CreateOrganization",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```